# How to convert a string of numbers without decimal points to a integer?

Tags: javascript

I have a string of numbers such as '9990' which in reality equals $99.90. I need to transform numbers like this to integers with decimal points. An acceptable outcome would be 99.90, 2.50, 250.25.

I have tried `parseFloat((parseInt("9990")/100).toFixed(2))` and the outcome has been 99.9 leaving the zero off. Thanks for your time and looking forward to a resolution.

Comment: The problem is because you are converting to float again `parseFloat` if is a number has no sense to put the right "0". So, if you what yo show to the user a number with format use it as `String` and operate the numbers as `Number/Float`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `float` value of `99.90` is `99.9` (trailing 0 does not have meaning).
If you want to print it with 2 decimals, you need to convert it to a string:

```js
const numberAsString = (parseInt("9990")/100).toFixed(2);
console.log(numberAsString);
```

Note that the `toFixed` method would return a string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use toFixed to get the value to 2 places

```
(parseInt("9990")/100).toFixed(2);
```